# Docker: what is the equivalent of the legacy --link parameter

Tags: docker, legacy

I need to connect my db container with my server container. Now I just red about the legacy parameter `--link`, which works perfect

```
$> docker run -d -P --name rethinkdb1 rethinkdb
$> docker run -d --link rethinkdb:db my-server
```

But, if this parameter will be dropped eventually, how would I do something like the above ?

Comment: The docs say you should use [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) instead.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think I get it now. If you add two container to the same network, their `/etc/hosts` file is updated automatically, right

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The docs says to use the [`docker network`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/) command instead (which is available since Docker 1.9.0 - 2015-11-03)

Instead of

```
$> docker run -d -P --name rethinkdb rethinkdb
$> docker run -d --link rethinkdb:rethinkdb my-server
```

you will now use

```
$> docker network create --name my-network
$> docker run -d -P --name rethinkdb1 --net=my-network rethinkdb
$> docker run -d --net=my-network my-server
```

Note that in the new form, container names are used, while before you were able to define an *alias*.

When two containers are part of the same network, their `/etc/hosts` file is updated so that you can use the container names instead of their IP addresses.

Comment: In docker version 18.06.1-ce `docker network create --name my-network` returns `unknown flag: --name` whereas `docker network create -my-network` seems to work just fine