# Unable to register docker selenium remote node to selenium hub remote host with docker

Tags: docker

I'm trying to connect the `docker selenium remote node` to `remote docker hub`, But it's not connecting, it shows the connection refused exception in Grid console(`http://localhost:4444/grid/console`) as in below screeshot.

Grid Screenshot:

[image]

The command I used to run the Hub on Machine A:
Hub:

```
docker run -d -p 4446:4444 --name selenium-hub -P selenium/hub
```

and command I used to register Node in Machine B on same network is:

```
docker run -d -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=10.7.30.9 -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444 selenium/node-firefox-debug:latest
```

But getting an error like this:

```
DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to 172.17.0.2:5555 [/172.17.0.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on docker, but it looks like you haven't linked both the hub and the node using the `--link` option. Without that linking the containers I don't think will talk to each other which explains why your registration itself is failing.

Can you please use the `--link` option and try again as detailed [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#selenium-grid-hub-and-nodes).

All said and done, it looks like the option `--link` is getting deprecated in docker and there are alternatives for that. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34623650) StackOverFlow post for understanding the alternatives.

Comment: I was able to connect to hub from earlier version of **node-firefox-debug (node-firefox-debug:2.53.1)** with the command `docker run -d -p 5555:5555 -p 5900:5900 -e REMOTE_HOST="http://10.7.30.29:5555" -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR="10.7.30.9" -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT="4444" --name chrome-node selenium/node-firefox-debug:2.53.1`. But still not able to connect latest **node-firefox-debug**